# wpf MinHeight & Height

Tags: wpf, css

I am just going over some of the finer points in the project that Josh Smith included with his wonderful MSDN mvvm [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and noticed that his MainWindow has both the MinHeight/Width and Height/Width properties to set to same values. Wouldn't he have accomplished the same thing by just setting the minimums?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
MinWidth="650" MinHeight="420" 
Width="650" Height="420"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set Width and Height then the Window will get a default size from the OS.  It will still clamp it as described in [WPF Windows Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#WindowSize) based on MinWidth, MinHeight, MaxWidth, MaxHeight, and SizeToContent, but the initial size can definitely be larger than MinWidth by MinHeight.  You can try it yourself by creating a new WPF application and setting MinWidth and MinHeight to something small.